# Do puzzles that take longer to solve get more views?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Is there any data about whether the number of views a puzzle gets is related to how long it takes to get an accepted answer?

Do questions that are answered (and accepted) quickly get more views, or do questions that remain unsolved for longer get more views?

Comment: I tried to rewrite the question to clarify what you were asking.  Hopefully I got your intent right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is not easily answered, because how do you define the *length* of a puzzle? The amount of text written? The time it *presumably* needs for solving (impossible to quantify)? The time it took for the first answer to arrive? The time it took until the answer was accepted? 
Also, how do you define "more viewed" ? Viewed/Voted on by *differnt* users or just plain views?

Some of these things might be explorable with the queries, but others aren't.